# Geometry not transferring between data sets with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geopackage

I am working on a QGIS plugin.  The database for the plugin is a GeoPackage.  Part of the plugin includes the ability to import features from outside databases by clicking a button.

The problem I am having is that all the attributes that I am mapping from outside data to the plugin GeoPackage db are getting copied but the geometry is not.

The first thing I tried was:

```
new_model_feature = QgsFeature(model_fields)
new_model_feature.setGeometry(source_feature.geometry())
```

That did not work.  Then I tried:

```
new_model_feature = QgsFeature(model_fields)
source_geometry = QgsGeometry().fromWkb(source_feature.geometry().asWkb())
new_model_feature.setGeometry(source_geometry)
```

Nothing seems to be able to set the geometry correctly in the new feature.  Again, attributes copy (code not shown) but not geometry.  What am I missing here?  I open the attribute table in the GeoPackage and everything looks normal.  I set up my GeoPackage layer like this:

```
QgsVectorLayer('MultiLineString', 'Pipes', 'memory')
```

Other things I have tried don't seem to make a difference either:

- Change the geometry type of the plugin layer
- Export the external layer to shapefile before trying to import

Also, I have tried exploring the geometry by printing the WKT to console and get something like this:

```
MultiLineString ((2274935.15752089023590088 6929719.31379280984401703, 2274938.08763313293457031 6929258.37376980483531952))
```

which seems normal.

Any ideas?

I would really rather not deconstruct the WKT into components and then rebuild since that would be incredibly slow since, in my current project I am using the plugin for, the source data has hundreds of thousands of features I am trying to import and then keep synchronized over time.

EDIT:

Based on your comments @bugmenot123, I changed to edit session but I still can't get it to work.  Here is the whole method:

```
def sync_source(self, source_info):
    # use OGR specific exceptions   https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372385/converting-an-esri-gdb-to-gpkg-using-pyqgis
    ogr.UseExceptions()
    # get the driver
    driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("OpenFileGDB")
    try:
        gdb = driver.Open(source_info['SOURCE_LOCATION'], 0)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    imported_features = []
    source_num = source_info['DATA_SOURCE']
    model_layername = source_info['MODEL_LAYER']
    model_layer = self.project.werqs_db.layer_objects[model_layername]
    model_fields = model_layer.fields()
    source_layer_name = source_info['TABLE_NAME']
    source_layer_uri = f'{source_info["SOURCE_LOCATION"]}|layername={source_layer_name}'
    source_layer = QgsVectorLayer(source_layer_uri, source_layer_name, 'ogr')
    # BUILD UID LISTS
    source_UID_field = source_info['TABLE_UID_FIELD']
    source_layer_UIDs = set([])
    for source_feature in source_layer.getFeatures():  # source_layer_request
        source_UID = source_feature[source_UID_field]
        if source_UID in self.source_UIDs:  # duplicate, track but don't use
            self.source_duplicate_UIDs.append(source_UID)
        source_layer_UIDs.add(source_UID)
    import_UIDs = []
    # WORK ON IMPORTS
    model_layer.startEditing()
    features_to_import = []
    for source_feature in source_layer.getFeatures():
        source_UID = source_feature[source_UID_field]
        if source_UID in import_UIDs and source_UID not in self.source_duplicate_UIDs:
            imported_features.append(source_feature)
            new_model_feature = QgsFeature(model_fields)
            new_model_feature.setGeometry(source_feature.geometry())
            new_model_feature['UID'] = source_UID
            features_to_import.append(new_model_feature)
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage(f'there are {len(features_to_import)} features that are attempting addition', 'WaterwerQs Plugin', Qgis.Info)
    model_layer.addFeatures(features_to_import)
    model_layer.commitChanges()
    model_layer.updateExtents()
    self.iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```

Comment: Where exactly do you judge if it worked or not? Is `new_model_feature.geometry()` not the correct geometry after you `setGeometry`d it?

Comment: The features don't show up in the map.

Comment: model_layer_data_provider = model_layer.dataProvider()
        model_layer_data_provider.addFeatures(features_to_import)
        model_layer.commitChanges()
        model_layer.updateExtents()
        self.iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()

Comment: Does not help either

Comment: Why do you not add the feature directly via https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.addFeatures or https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.addFeatures  but using the low-level https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorDataProvider.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorDataProvider.addFeatures ? What does the return code say? Are you in edit mode? Your code sample is very sparse.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing an active edit mode and you might have an easier time using the high-level `QgsVectorLayer` methods instead of the low-level `QgsVectorDataProvider`.

Here is an example that should hopefully work, adjust the layer names:

```
source_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("a")[0]
target_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("b")[0]

source_feature = next(source_layer.getFeatures())

new_feature = QgsFeature()
new_feature.setGeometry(source_feature.geometry())

with edit(target_layer):
    success = target_layer.addFeature(new_feature)
if not success:
    print("Error...")
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a symbology issue that I missed.  No wonder it did not make sense.