# Cannot import QgsVectorLayer from osgeo.ogr

Tags: gdal, python-3, osgeo, qgsvectorlayer

I am trying to write a simple script to convert an ESRI geodatabase to a geopackage using gdal/ogr.
Here's the example I was using:

```
from osgeo import ogr

fgdb = r"C:\GIS\data\somefilegeodatabase.gdb"
outdb = r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\OK.gpkg" #Has to be created in advance
fileEncoding = "UTF-8"

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("OpenFileGDB")
data = driver.Open(fgdb, 0)

#List all layers in the file geodatabase
feature_class_list = []
for i in data:
    foo = i.GetName()
    feature_class_list.append(foo)

#Write to geopackage
for fc in feature_class_list:
    gdbLyr = QgsVectorLayer("{0}|layername={1}".format(fgdb, fc), fc, "ogr")
    print('Writing: ', fc)
    options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
    options.driverName = "GPKG"
    options.layerName = fc
    options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer
    options.EditionCapability = 0 #CanAddNewLayer 
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(gdbLyr, outdb, options)
```

Everything works until I get to this line: `gdbLyr = QgsVectorLayer("{0}|layername={1}".format(fgdb, fc), fc, "ogr")` .  This throws an error: `NameError: name 'QgsVectorLayer' is not defined`
I've tried importing in QgsVectorLayer directly from osgeo, but that doesn't work. Has this been deprecated or replaced in `osgeo` or am I importing it incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in [another answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/466186/2856) [`QgsVectorLayer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.32/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#module-QgsVectorLayer) is not and has never been part of the GDAL python bindings.

I think you want [`gdal.VectorTranslate()`](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.VectorTranslate).

At it's simplest, your code turns into:

```
from osgeo import gdal

fgdb = r"C:\GIS\data\somefilegeodatabase.gdb"
outdb = r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\OK.gpkg" #Does not need to be created in advance

gdal.VectorTranslate(outdb, fgdb)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks for the concise answer!

Answer (score 4):

The osgeo module has never had QgsVectorLayer. That belong to qgis.core module.

https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorLayer.html

Comment: Ugh, thats kinda what I suspected. My example above was from another post I was using as an example (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372385/converting-an-esri-gdb-to-gpkg-using-pyqgis) and there was no mention of it; only a simple import of ogr from osgeo.